# Connect Oracle DB from SSIS using ODBC?

Tags: oracle, ssis, odbc

I have been trying to connect to an Oracle Database using SSIS(Visual Studio) using ODBC as the connection manager.

My OS is Windows 7 (64 bit), Visual Studio 2010 (32-bit) and Oracle 11G is 64 bit.

While connecting to Oracle 11G using Visual Studio via ODBC I am greeted with the following error:

'The specified DSN has an architecture mismatch between driver and application'

This is understandable as Visual Studio is 32 bit and the server I am trying connect to is 64 bit.

Possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Install both the 32 and 64 bit providers for oracle.  This will allow you to configure the connection (in 32 bit) and run the package in 64 bit.

Also, check out attunity: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44582

This is a free oracle source and destination component from Microsoft.  You'll find that it uses native oracle interfaces and runs much faster than ODBC.

m

Comment: Attunity components are available only on Enterprise Editions of SSIS.

Comment: @Ferdipux this is a good point.  Hope Sharktooth has enterprise!

Comment: I have only got the Premium edition. Also, tried installing Oracle 11g 32 bit Client but that failed as my os is 64-bit. Can you provide me with the Oracle 32 bit providers for SSIS?

Comment: You do not need the client, you need the data providers: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html, also premium edition refers to visual studio.  We are talking about the SQL installation.  Is that enterprise edition?

Comment: It is: 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6220.0 (X64)   Mar 19 2015 12:32:14   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)' Also, I couldn't get Attunity to work but I will try again after install the Oracle providers.

Comment: SQL 2008R2 requires an earlier version, 2.0, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29283